how to generalize a version of IVT theorem
We know, with the IVT theorem: if $f(0)=0,f'(0)>0$ and $f(a)<0$ for a continuous function, one can deduce that there exists at least $c \in ]0, a[$ such that $f(c)=0$.
could we generalize this result to 2d dimension on a convex domain $\Omega$ using $\nabla f>0$ on the edge of $\Omega$ if we have $f(a) < 0$ for some $a \in \partial\Omega$?

What does $\nabla f>0$ mean in this context?

Thank you for your response, I search a condition contains $\nabla f$ like $\nabla f \cdot n>0$ or something like that.

Typically, the IVT applied in higher dimensions involves "one-dimensionalizing" the function. For two points $x,y\in\Omega$ and $f\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$, we just define
$$g(t)=f(tx+(1-t)y).$$
If $f$ is differentiable and $\nabla f$ is continuous, then we can compute $\nabla g(0)=y^\top\nabla f(y)$ and $\nabla g(1)=x^\top \nabla f(x)$ using the chain rule. So, in this higher-dimensional setting, it would be something like "If $\nabla g(0)>0$ and $\nabla g(1)<0$, then there exists $\tau\in (0,1)$ such that $\nabla g(\tau)=0$." Expressed in the notation of $f$, this would mean that there is a point $z=\tau x+(1-\tau)y$ on the line segment connecting the two vectors $x$ and $y$ such that $z^\top\nabla f(z)=0$.
One thing which wasn't quite clear to me from the question is the statement "$\nabla f > 0$" since $\nabla f$ is a vector and there isn't an order on vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. However, if this is meant componentwise, then one can derive a similar guarantee: If, for two points $x,y\in\Omega$, $\nabla f(x)>0$ (componentwise) and $\nabla f(y)<0$ (componentwise), then for each component $i$ there exists a point $z$ on the line segment between $x$ and $y$ such that the $i$th component of $\nabla^i f(z)=0$. However, the components do not need to be zero simultaneously, so importantly, this does not guarantee that $\nabla f=0$ anywhere. This result can be proven by applying the IVT to the continuous function $h(\tau)=\nabla^i f(\tau x + (1-\tau) y)$.

thank you for your response, we have $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^2$. (a system contain $F_1(x,y)=0,F_2(x,y)=0)$. In your response you have introduce $g(t)=f(tx+(1-t)y)$ but $f$ depends on two variables $f(x,y)$, also i don't understand $\nabla g(0)$ since $g: [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ in this case we have $g'$. In my research i find the theorem of hadamard on a ball and the condition is $<f(x),x> \leq 0 $ on the edge of $\Omega$ but i want a condition contain $\nabla f$ like in 1d!!!

As-stated, $f$ depends on a single variable in $\Omega$. For this example, we treat $x$ and $y$ as fixed vectors, and we only let $t\in[0,1]$ be the one-dimensional variable that changes. Each evaluation of $g$ at $t$ is defined as the evaluation of $f$ at the vector $tx+(1-t)y$, which is guaranteed to reside in $\Omega$ since it is convex.
